# Pull column value from second to last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stuck in a loop of figuring out a game plan for this in SQL. Below is my sample data. I'm trying to create another column called "Starting Balance" which would be the amount in "Ending Balance" for the previous LINE. When I have that, I would only like to display where reason = count and forget about the rest.

I can't even fathom what approach to take and any advice would be appreciated.

**Sample Data:**

| ITEM ID | ITEM | LAST UPDATED | REASON | ENDING BALANCE | LINE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/1/2020 | Correction | 400 | 1 |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/2/2020 | Correction | 450 | 2 |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/3/2020 | Count | 500 | 3 |

**Expected Output:**

| ITEM ID | ITEM | LAST UPDATED | REASON | Starting Balance | ENDING BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/3/2020 | Count | 450 | 500 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if "previous LINE" means the row with Lastupdated before current row:

```
select * from (
    select * , lag(ENDING_BALANCE,1,0) over (partition by ItemId order by LASTUPDATED) as Starting Balance
    from table
) t where t.REASON = 'count'
```

Comment: That seemed to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I can't bugtest this, but maybe something like:

```
SELECT
  a.ITEM_ID,
  a.ITEM,
  a.LAST_UPDATED,
  "Count" AS REASON,
  b.ENDING_BALANCE AS Starting_Balance,
  a.ENDING_BALANCE AS ENDING_BALANCE,
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b
ON a.ITEM_ID = b.ITEM_ID, a.LINE = b.LINE + 1
```

Note that we're joining two copies of the same table together here and labeling them a and b.
No clue if you can do ONs like that, but you could also make the join table have a LINE +1 column  which you then use to join.

Comment: I tried this approach, but don't think you can use the row value "Count"  to create another column. At least it didn't work for me